# Sub-quadratic Kolmogorov-Arnold?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, computational-complexity, continuity

The [Kolmogorov-Arnold representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem) says, essentially, that when computing a continuous function, the only multivariate function you really need is addition.  (Somewhat) more precisely, it says that for any continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we can write $f$ as
$$f(x)=f(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{q=0}^{2n} \Phi_q\left(\sum_{p=1}^n \phi_{q,p}(x_p)\right)$$
If we count function evaluations (the additions, the $\Phi_q$'s and the $\phi_{q,p}$'s), we perform $O(n^2)$ operations.

Is there an alternate representation that only involves sub-quadratic complexity?

If there are additional assumptions that might make this true (e.g., non-negative definiteness in the spirit of [Mercer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem)), that would also be helpful to know.